# What order should I use guitar amp, sims and cabs in?

Tags: guitar, production

Please explain to me what’s what and why?

There are many plugins on the Internet. I do not understand. There are amplifiers, pre-amplifiers, pedals. Then there are cabinets, impulse loaders, what are they?
And please explain for a live performance what you need and how to use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're talking about software. Perhaps it would help us more if you specified the software you're using.

I have no experience using software to alter the sound of your guitar, but can tell you about the hardware equivalents and what they do.

- Preamps are the first stage of amplification. They usually include some sort of gain to allow you to overdrive the signal and produce a distorted sound that is used a lot in rock and blues. As a simplification, they are used to add overdrive to your sound, each preamp having a different "colour" or personality.
- Amplifiers are the second stae of amplification, and generally increase the volume of the signal without overdriving it too much (this is a generalisation... some amplifier stages can also distort your sound). They generally add volume without colouring too much.
- A cabinet is the box where the speaker is hosted. It can give a certain "colour" to your sound, so it's part of the overall tone of your guitar.
- Pedals are compact units that allow you to introduce some effect to your signal chain. You can add a reverb, a delay (also called "echo" sometimes), phaser, flanger, etc. Some of these can be used before they reach the preamp, some between the preamp and the amp (in the so-called "effects loop").
- I don't know what an impulse loader is.

If you want to emulate the sound of plugging your guitar to a combo amp, all you need is

> Guitar -> preamp -> amp -> cabinet

If you want to introduce some effects, your signal chain could look like this:

> Guitar -> effects that affect pitch and tone (wah-wah, overdrive, distortion) -> preamp -> time and phase effects (reverb, delay, chorus...) -> amp -> cabinet

There is not single "right" way to use them. The above is just a very common pattern. It's up to you to experiment to find your own sound.

Comment: An impulse loader is a generic [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) processor. These can be used to simulate any [LTI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_time-invariant_system) system, which includes EQ/filters, delay, reverb and (approximately) speakers/cabinets. Normally they're used for reverb or cabinets, because for EQ and delay there are more practical alternatives.

Comment: It's not really true that amps (you seem to mean _power amps_) don't affect the signal much apart from boosting. Boosting would be completely irrelevant in software, that's just a trivial multiplication. Actually a power amp can clip/distort just as much as a preamp (though in case of power amps this necessarily comes with such high speaker volume levels that guitarists may choose no to go there). Tube power amps _are_ regularly overdriven at least a bit, since particularly the [compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_range_compression) this incurs is quite desirable.

Comment: Careful about  "assume" --  https://xkcd.com/1339/  and be sure to read the   alt-text   :-)